# Openlayers V6 Backgroundfill text only applies on last text element

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

A couple of weeks ago we've updated our software with the newest openlayers version (6.1.1). The previous version was 5.3.0, where we didn't experience the problem.

We have a vector layer, and for each feature, we draw the name on the map. We apply style to these texts, and also add a background, so the text is always readable.

```
var fontColor = "black";
var backgroundColor = "white";
var backgroundFill = new ol.style.Fill({
   color: backgroundColor
});
var text = new ol.style.Text({ fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: fontColor }), backgroundFill: backgroundFill, text: "text" });
labelStyle.setText(text);
```

Somehow in the newest version (6.1) of openlayers, the backgroundFill is only applied on the last text element.

If I randomly pick a fontColor which will be differrent for each feature, this is correctly applied on each feature.

Has the functionality of the backgroundFill-property changed? Or is there another way to apply backgroundFill with the newest version of Openlayers so that it is applied to all elements?

Comment: It's a bug related to changes in the way declutter works https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10098